# How to get Options Menu to work on Nexus 7?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

I am programming an app with an Options Menu in my Main Activity. This Options Menu works fine on my HTC Android Incredible device. However, when I test it with a Nexus 7 emulator the program crashes.  How can I get the options menu to work on the Nexus 7? Any ideas on this? Thank you in advance. Here is the code I am using.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.testmenu1, menu);
// your code...
return true;} // true if you want the menu to be displayed; false otherwise
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Just prepare ourself for unexpected arguments...

    if (menuInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo)) {
        return;
    }

    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    switch (mi.position) {
    case 0:

        menu.add("Product 1");

        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 3:
        menu.add("mouse menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 4:
        menu.add("panda menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 5:
        menu.add("rabbit menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Carousel carousel = (Carousel) findViewById(R.id.carousel);
    carousel.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            CarouselItem item = (CarouselItem) parent.getChildAt(position);

            // HERE: Force context menu
            carousel.showContextMenuForChild(item);
            Toast.makeText(
                    MainActivity.this,
                    String.format("%s has been clicked",
                            ((CarouselItem) parent.getChildAt(position))
                                    .getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }});

    carousel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            final TextView txt = (TextView) (findViewById(R.id.selected_item));

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                txt.setText("The cat (Felis catus), also known as the domestic cat or housecat to distinguish it from other felids and felines, is a small, usually furry, domesticated, carnivorous mammal that is valued by humans for its companionship and for its ability to hunt vermin and household pests. Cats have been associated with humans for at least 9,500 years, and are currently the most popular pet in the world. Owing to their close association with humans, cats are now found almost everywhere in the world.");
                break;
            case 1:
                txt.setText("The hippopotamus (Hippopotamus amphibius), or hippo, from the ancient Greek for \"river horse\" (), is a large, mostly herbivorous mammal in sub-Saharan Africa, and one of only two extant species in the family Hippopotamidae (the other is the Pygmy Hippopotamus.) After the elephant, the hippopotamus is the third largest land mammal and the heaviest extant artiodactyl.");
                break;
            case 2:
                txt.setText("A monkey is a primate, either an Old World monkey or a New World monkey. There are about 260 known living species of monkey. Many are arboreal, although there are species that live primarily on the ground, such as baboons. Monkeys are generally considered to be intelligent. Unlike apes, monkeys usually have tails. Tailless monkeys may be called \"apes\", incorrectly according to modern usage; thus the tailless Barbary macaque is called the \"Barbary ape\".");
                break;
            case 3:
                txt.setText("A mouse (plural: mice) is a small mammal belonging to the order of rodents. The best known mouse species is the common house mouse (Mus musculus). It is also a popular pet. In some places, certain kinds of field mice are also common. This rodent is eaten by large birds such as hawks and eagles. They are known to invade homes for food and occasionally shelter.");
                break;
            case 4:
                txt.setText("The giant panda, or panda (Ailuropoda melanoleuca, literally meaning \"black and white cat-foot\") is a bear native to central-western and south western China.[4] It is easily recognized by its large, distinctive black patches around the eyes, over the ears, and across its round body. Though it belongs to the order Carnivora, the panda's diet is 99% bamboo.");
                break;
            case 5:
                txt.setText("Rabbits (or, colloquially, bunnies) are small mammals in the family Leporidae of the order Lagomorpha, found in several parts of the world. There are eight different genera in the family classified as rabbits, including the European rabbit (Oryctolagus cuniculus), cottontail rabbits (genus Sylvilagus; 13 species), and the Amami rabbit (Pentalagus furnessi, an endangered species on Amami, Japan)");
                break;
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(CarouselAdapter<?> parent) {
        }

    });

    registerForContextMenu(carousel);
}

}
```

LogCat Error:

```
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.carouseldemo.main/com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at   com.carouseldemo.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:108)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     ... 11 more
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     ... 22 more
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel$ImageAdapter.SetImages(Carousel.java:778)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.<init>  (Carousel.java:253)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel.<init>     (Carousel.java:204)
01-31 19:55:42.221: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     ... 25 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Nexus 7 emulator is too much heavy-weight. If you PC configuration is low, then try not using it.

Comment: What do you have the device heap size set to in the AVD settings? You are trying to load a lot of bitmaps, any idea of the size of them?

Comment: You should inflate your menu in onCreateOptionsMenu() instead of onPrepareOptionsMenu(). You can then handle options in onOptionItemSelected().